# Rails validations and initializations with interdependent fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

After coding in Rails for a couple of years, I still don't understand the Rails Way for more advanced concepts. The Rails Way is so specific about convention over configuration, however when you get into Enterprise coding, all rules go out the window and everyone writes blogs with non-standard way of doing things. Here's another one of those situations: contextual validations where the context is a little more complex (fields depend on each other). Basically in a shipping application, I need to initialize an AR object with request params and with some calculated values. The calculated values are dependent on the request params, and I'm not sure how to initialize and validate my member variables.

```
table mailpieces
  mail_class
  weight
  sort_code
  t_indicator_id
end

class Mailpiece
  validates_presence_of: :mail_class
  validates_presence_of: :weight
  validates_presence_of: :sort_code
  validates_presence_of: :t_indicator_id

  def some_kind_of_initializer
    if mail_class == 'Priority'
      sort_code = '123'
    elsif mail_class == 'Express'
      if weight < 1
        sort_code = '456'
      else
        sort_code = '789'
      end
    end

    t_indicator = ndicator.find_by(name: 'blah')
    if sort_code = '456'
      t_indicator = Indicator.find_by(name: 'foobar')
    end
  end
end

mailpiece = Mailpiece.new(
  mail_class: params[:mail_class],
  weight: params[:weight])

#mailpiece.some_kind_of_initializer ?!

raise 'SomeError' if !mailpiece.valid?
```

What should some_kind_of_initializer be?

1. Override of ActiveRecord initialize? That's not good practice.
2. after_initialize. More Rails Way-sy.
3. Custom method called after
   Mailpiece.new (e.g. mailpiece.some_kind_of_initializer)

Whichever of the above choices, the problem is that the initialization of sort_code and t_indicator depends on mail_class and weight being valid. Given that mail_class and weight should be not null before I enter some_kind_of_initializer, how should I write my validations?

1. Extract all validations into a json schema validation. More complex business rules around mail_class and weight are difficult to write in a json schema.
2. Extract all validations into some type of Data Transfer Object validation class. Moves away from the Rails Way of doing things. Feels like I'm writing in .NET/Java and I'm afraid that Rails will kick my azz later (in validations, testing, etc.).
3. Assign sort_code only if mail_class and weight have been initialized. This seems to be most Rails Way to write things, but it's tough. So many if/else. This is just a simple example, but my mailpiece has references that have references and they all do these type of validations. If this is the right answer, then I'm getting a gut feeling that it might be easier to move ALL validations and ALL initializations to an external class/module - perhaps getting close to option #2.

Option 3 code rewrite

```
def some_kind_of_initializer
  if mail_class && weight
    if (mail_class == 'Priority')
      sort_code = '123'
    elsif (mail_class == 'Express')
      if weight < 1
        sort_code = '456'
      else
        sort_code = '789'
      end
    end
  end

  if sort_code
    t_indicator = Indicator.find_by(name: 'blah')
    if sort_code = '456'
      t_indicator = Indicator.find_by(name: 'foobar')
    end
  end
end
```

I'd love to hear your opinion on this. It seems to me this is such a popular use case of AR and I'm not sure what to do. Again, this is a just a simple case. My Mailpiece model has many other references that have dependencies on the mailpiece object properties and their own interdependencies in the same style as above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it helps or I understood your question correctly, but maybe using "case" instead of if/elsif/else, the ternary operator, some lazy assignment and some extra validations can give your code a better "rails" feeling.

With lazy assignment I mean that you could wait to initialize sort_code and t_indicator until you actually need to use it or save it.

```
def sort_code
  return self[:sort_code] if self[:sort_code].present?

  sort_code = case mail_class
              when 'Priority' then '123'
              when 'Express'
                weight < 1 ? '456' : '789' if weight
              end
  self[:sort_code] = sort_code
end
```

That way, sort_code gets initialized right before you need to use it the first time so you can do Mailpiece.new(mail_class: 'Something') and forget about initializing sort_code right away.

The problem would come when you need to save the object and you never called mailpiece.sort_code. You could have a before_validation callback that justs calls sort_code to initialize it in case it wasn't already.

The same can be done for t_indicator.

I would also add some context in your validations

```
validates_presence_of :weight, if: Proc.new{|record| 'Express' == record.mail_class} #you could add some helper method "is_express?" so you can just do "if: :is_express?"
validates_presence_of :sort_code, if: Proc.new{|record| 'Priority' == record.mail_class or 'Express' == record.mail_class && record.weight.present?}
```

Sorry if I missunderstood your question, I didn't even use your options haha.

Comment: I can't add Procs to the validation definitions, since my weight and sort_code validations are much more complex than the given example. But let's say I would write custom validators to encapsulate the business logic, even with the lazy initialization solution, how do I know if mail_class and weight are valid at the point I try to calculate sort_code? Should I call mailpiece.valid? before I ever access mailpiece.sort_code?

Comment: Should I make that a general rule: all calculated fields are deferred until I need them and everything that comes from the user request can be validated immediately? What if I want to write some validations concerning sort_code (e.g. raise if mail_class = 'Priority' && weight > 70.0 && sort_code == 'XXX')?

Comment: I don't think you need to validate mail_class or weight there, just do something with the valid values and nothing with the invalid ones and sort_code will be nil if mail_class or weight are invalid. You should, though, consider the possible nil value of sort_code.

I'm not sure if you should make a general rule, I couldn't generalize without knowledge of the real code. I don't think there's a best practice or something about this.

About the validation, the moment you call sort_code == 'XXX' it gets initialized and compared to 'XXX', just remember sort_code could be nil.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
class Mailpiece
  validates_presence_of: :mail_class
  validates_presence_of: :weight
  validates_presence_of: :sort_code
  validates_presence_of: :t_indicator_id

  def default_mail_class
    'Priority'
  end

  def default_sort_code
    mail_class = mail_class || default_mail_class
    if mail_class == 'Priority'
      '123'
    elsif mail_class == 'Express'
      weight < 1 ? '456' : '789'
    end
  end
end
```

Then, when you needed to figure out t_indicator, just do it as-needed:

```
def is_foobar_indicator?
  sort_code || default_sort_code == '456'
end

def t_indicator
    indicator_params = {name: is_foobar_indicator? ? 'foobar' : 'blah'}
    Indicator.find_by(indicator_params)
end
```

So you can still have the validation on sort_code (assuming that is user provided) but still use defaults when looking at t_indicator. I don't know how complicated the rest of your model is, but I would suggest not looking up values until you need them. Also, after_initialize is risky   because it runs your code exactly where it claims - after every initialize, so if you run a query for N items but do nothing but find on them, or wind up not using the defaults you're setting, after_initialize runs N times for nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the after_initialize tip and the "not looking up values until you need them". This solution still suffers from the same issue: mail_class and weight should be validated before the default_sort_code method is called.

Comment: If you have a default sort_code which depends on the mail_class value, then you should also have a default mail_class value. The same potentially with weight, since weight comes in to play if mail_class == 'Express'. In this case, nothing is set, so you need to provide all of the defaults for it to do its job of giving you the sort_code. But if there is no default mail_class or weight, then you can have no default sort_code based on it, so that goes out the window, too, unless you use a static value as the default, which then really simplifies this. Also, I updated the answer for default class

Comment: I am curious: You have presence validations on mail_code, sort_code, weight, etc, but you're also asking about defaults. You either have some or all of those values from the user. If one of them is not present, your model does not validate. If all of them are present, then there is no reason for defaults.  If you have default values, why is it being forced on the user? Shouldn't you just fall back to the default values?

Comment: I don't think I mentioned anything about defaults in my original post. There are no defaults for any values. It's all initialized based on the user's request params. Just to reiterate my question, what the best way of validating sort_code when sort_code is based on mail_class and weight and those need to be validated first?